# SharePoint 2016 Top Navigation Edit Links not working@

Tags: top-navigation, edit-links

I am using SP 2016, When I add any subsite it gets added to the top nav and its pages gets added underneath the site.
eg.

```
Subsite 1
- Page-1
- Page-2
- Page-3
- Page-4
```

When I go to *Top Navigation*, click *Edit links* options and try to remove some links from the dropdown using X sign, nothing happens. I am able to do drag and drop but for some reason not able to remove and rename the links in top navigation.

However, I am able to do it for the left navigation.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: I think you need to check the Site Settings > Navigation - here there are more details navigation settings.  Personally I never use the Edit Links options.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit/remove top navigation items via **Site Settings > Navigation**, then under **Structural Navigation: Editing and Sorting**, you'll see your links in a list (top nav items are under **Global Navigation**)